# How to make Kaomoji and Symbols tabs appear on Windows 10 emoji dialog?

Tags: windows-10, input, symbols, emoji-keyboard

MS has added the Japanese Kaomoji and Japanese Compatibility Symbols in Windows 10 [insider build 17661](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/05/03/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17661/#0c3G257f0vCWhWky.97)

[image: emoji pane]

I'm using build 17746 and I have Japanese keyboard on my PC, but I can't see those things appear. So how can I use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the article you provide: [insider build 17661](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/05/03/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17661/#0c3G257f0vCWhWky.97), I find this sentence：**You can browse between Emoji, Kaomoji, and Symbol input when Chinese (Simplified) is the active locale.**

[image]

I think we need to add Chinese (Simplified,China) language, and when we switch to this input method, then we can see these three emoticons. This is the case in my environment.

[image]

**We can see that Emoji, Kaomoji, and Symbol are displaying as below:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

We can add **Chinese (Simplified, China)** language like this:

1. Navigate to **Control Panel->region->Administrative tab->Change system locale->Region Setting**.
2. In **Current system locale**, select **Chinese (Simplified, China)**.
3. Click "**OK**".

[image]

Comment: yeah I've just noticed I overlooked the Chinese part. But it's really strange that a Japanese thing is enabled for only Chinese locale